# How do you do Pooling of requests in python with a big list of elements?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have got a list of links to visit. Long list:

```
fake_list = [...] #It does contains links
```

I do have to visit each one of those links and check whether is a dead link -404- or live link -200-. If I loop through every link making a request to it it will fail after a couple, So I decide to go for multithreading, Pooling in this case and it worked well for a medium list? [1 - 8 links?]. See code below:

```
import futures
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as pool:
        results = list(pool.map(self.check_url, fake_list ))
```

That code works mapping every link with a 'check_url' method that create a tuple based on what the link characteristics ( url, status, access_date ).

Even if I increment the number of workers, if the 'fake_list' contains lots of it, it won´t work. :(

**My question is:**

> What can I do to manage more capacity? to be able to 'ask' to more
>   links whether they are alive or not?

Kind regards.

```
###################################################################
```

I think the problem was in the links I was fetching. If I fetch, let´s say, 100 broken links from google, it will work smoothly the code I´ll put below:

```
async def fetch(url):    
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False)
    async with aiohttp.request('get', url, connector=connector) as response:
        return response
        #return await response.read()

async def run(loop, r):
    url = "https://google.com/{}" # IMPORTANT!!!!!
    tasks = []
    for i in range(r):
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(url.format(i)))
        tasks.append(task)

    responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    # you now have all response bodies in this variable
    print_responses(responses)

def print_responses(result):
    for i in result:
      print(i)
      print("status: {}".format(i.status))
      print("url: {}".format(i.url))
      print("headers: {}".format(i.headers))
      print("date: {}".format(i.headers['DATE']))
      print("\n\n")      


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(loop,100))
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

If instead having the url pointing to `google.com/xxxx` I have use this link:

`url = "https://torrentz.eu/{}"`  it does fail and the result is the one below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\Desktop\Entura\entura_code_test_seb\entura_code_test\linkchecker\corelogic\linkchecker - copia.py", line 59, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(future)
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 387, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 241, in _step
    result = coro.throw(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\Desktop\Entura\entura_code_test_seb\entura_code_test\linkchecker\corelogic\linkchecker - copia.py", line 43, in run
    responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 361, in __iter__
    yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 296, in _wakeup
    future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 241, in _step
    result = coro.throw(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\Desktop\Entura\entura_code_test_seb\entura_code_test\linkchecker\corelogic\linkchecker - copia.py", line 32, in fetch
    async with aiohttp.request('get', url, connector=connector) as response:
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 537, in __aenter__
    self._resp = yield from self._coro
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 197, in _request
    raise aiohttp.ClientResponseError() from exc
aiohttp.errors.ClientResponseError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\Desktop\Entura\entura_code_test_seb\entura_code_test\linkchecker\corelogic\linkchecker - copia.py", line 59, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(future)
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 387, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 241, in _step
    result = coro.throw(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\Desktop\Entura\entura_code_test_seb\entura_code_test\linkchecker\corelogic\linkchecker - copia.py", line 43, in run
    responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 361, in __iter__
    yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 296, in _wakeup
    future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 241, in _step
    result = coro.throw(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\Desktop\Entura\entura_code_test_seb\entura_code_test\linkchecker\corelogic\linkchecker - copia.py", line 32, in fetch
    async with aiohttp.request('get', url, connector=connector) as response:
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 537, in __aenter__
    self._resp = yield from self._coro
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 197, in _request
    raise aiohttp.ClientResponseError() from exc
aiohttp.errors.ClientResponseError
>>>
```

Seems like the server refused all my request to that site???

Any thoughts in here??

Thanks!

Comment: You do not need threads nor multiprocess, you need [asyncio](https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I have been applying what´s in there but I got this as error:
`ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed `
In the way I did before it I disabled warnings by doing this: `urllib3.disable_warnings()` 

But that is not working anymore, any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know. Maybe try with a simple example, using your first code but only with the built-in module `ascyncio`, or check if there is some ssl disabling option in `aiohttp`.